# Who should NOT accept upon himself a voluntary fast?

Tags: fast-days, rosh-chodesh-new-month, kedusha-holiness, shovavim-tat

Taanit 12b states that only if one has the ability is fasting positive. 
The Shulchan Aruch (YD 245:17) states that a *melamed* a Torah teacher of children should not fast, (see Aruch ha-Shulchan) a voluntary fast so that it does not detract from his teaching. 
Is the determining factor whether or not one could continue concentrating on his daily activities? Does one's productivity need to remain at the same level as when one is well-nourished? Are there health risks for youth?

Examples of voluntary fasts include erev Rosh Hodesh and BaHaB (Yamim Bet ve-Hei during the weeks of Shovavim).

Comment: Abbou You wrote "whether or not one could continue concentrating **on his daily activities**? Does one's **productivity** need to remain at the same level ... I do not see any mention in your quote from the SA, about "daily activities" or about "productivity",  only about "detraction from **learning**.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore I was assuming that for the talmid chacham, learning is _his_ daily activity, and perhaps it could be applied to anyone and their daily activities.

Comment: Why do you assume that the issue is one of not being able to concentrate on "daily activities" Rather than loss of qualitative Torah study?

Comment: @rib there was no such assumption. There was a _question_ whether that's true.